# How can I find and replace decimal numbers among whole numbers in a column in R?

Tags: r, replace

I am working with a dataset that came from a machine.
In one column, all values are whole numbers without any decimals, but sometimes the machine recorded some numbers with decimals.
In this column, all numbers are in order from 1 to 9 and then 1 to 9 again but with different replicates. For example, there might be five of 1 or three of 2.

```
1
1
1
2
3
4
5
8.6
6
7
7
7
7
8
9
9
4.2
1
1
1
2
3
```

How can I find these numbers (With decimal) among whole numbers and replace them with other values (Not rounded) or remove these numbers from my dataset?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `dput()` to recreate your data set and post the result here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dataframe is called `df` and the column is `V1` you can identify values which are decimals by

```
df$V1 %% 1 != 0
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[14] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

If you want to replace these values (let's say with `NA`)

```
df$V1[df$V1 %% 1 != 0] <- NA
```

If you want to drop decimal values you can do :

```
df <- df[df$V1 %% 1 == 0, , drop = FALSE]
```

Answer (score 2):

simply use the `ifelse()` function

```
 d<-c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8.6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 9, 9, 4.2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3)


e<-ifelse(d==as.integer(d), d, NA) # instead of NA you can insert any value you want.
```

result:

```
1  1  1  2  3  4  5 NA  6  7  7  7  7  8  9  9 NA  1  1  1  2  3
```

you said you didn't want to just round the values but if it was an option a simple `d<-as.integer(d)` would solve the problem as well.