# How to return all values in a vector with decimals?

Tags: r

I have a dataset with a column for IDs. Few of these IDs are not integers but have decimals points. The dataset is very large, so I cannot just skim through. Here an example:

```
ID <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5.19, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10.732)
```

I would like to return the value and/or position of those with decimals. So something like:

```
[5] 5.19
[10] 10.732
```

Is this possible?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64076671/how-can-i-find-and-replace-decimal-numbers-among-whole-numbers-in-a-column-in-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values,

```
ID[ID != as.integer(ID)]
# [1]  5.190 10.732
```

positions,

```
which(ID != as.integer(ID))
# [1]  5 10
```

and altogether.

```
setNames(ID, seq_along(ID))[ID != as.integer(ID)]
#     5     10 
# 5.190 10.732
```

Answer (score 1):

You could consider the modulo operation and then comparing the results with 0:

```
dplyr::near(ID %% 1, 0)
```

that would return:

```
 [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Then, you can negate it and return the positions of non-integers:

```
which(!dplyr::near(ID %% 1, 0))

[1]  5 10
```

Alternatively, you could convert it to a character vector and then look for the decimal point:

```
which(grepl("[0-9]\\.[0-9]", as.character(ID)))

[1]  5 10
```